# VB.net get form that event was raised in

Tags: vb.net, forms, reference

I'm stuck. My application has this 'standard form style'. I have a function that makes the form looks standard. In this function it makes all kinds of objects. For example a Panel:

Then the function adds an event handler for when the panel is hovered:

```
 ' Add drag panel
 Dim panel_drag As New Panel
 With panel_drag
      .Size = New Size(this.size.Width, 40)
      .Location = New Point(0, 0)
      .BackColor = var_global.color_base
 End With

 AddHandler panel_drag.MouseEnter, AddressOf drag_panel_MouseSwitch
 AddHandler panel_drag.MouseLeave, AddressOf drag_panel_MouseSwitch         
 this.Controls.Add(panel_drag)
```

'this' is the form that called the function.

```
Public Shared Sub drag_panel_MouseSwitch(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

drag_panel_switch(sender)

End Sub
```

Then the drag_panel_switch function:

```
Public Shared Sub drag_panel_switch(ByVal this As Object, ByVal sender As Object)

    If (this.BackColor = var_global.color_base) Then
        this.BackColor = var_global.color_base_dark
        <form>.cross_exit.BackColor = var_global.color_base_dark
    Else
        this.BackColor = var_global.color_base
        <form>.cross_exit.BackColor = var_global.color_base
    End If

End Sub
```

Now 'form' has to be the form that the drag_panel is in. How do I get this form?

EDIT:

I see that the problem isn't totally clear. In the application multiple forms have the same drag_panel. When for example I hover over drag_panel in 'form 1', how does the function know it was 'form 1' and not 'form 2'. Or: How do I make `<form>` into `form_1` (or `form_2`)

The problem is that I use a global Sub. In this global function it makes a drag_panel for every form that calls this function. When I hover drag_panel drag_panel_switch is called. Because drag_panel_switch is also a global Sub I can't use Me. I need another way to reference to the form that the drag_panel was hovered in.
Thanks in advance,

Luud Janssen

p.s. I really did my best finding the answer...

Comment: `this.Parent` is the container of the control--in this case, the form.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use Me for `<form>`. How do I get Me in this case?

Comment: Why can't you use `Me` or `this.Parent`?  I'm confused.

Comment: I edited my problem, maybe it's clear now.

Answer (score 3):

The sender is the panel in the mouse events, you can use this to get the parent form.

```
Public Shared Sub drag_panel_MouseSwitch(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

dim panel as panel = ctype(sender, panel)

drag_panel_switch(panel)

End Sub

Public Shared Sub drag_panel_switch(ByVal this As panel)

    Dim myForm as BaseForm = CType(this.FindForm(), BaseForm)

    ' Use this if you are using the interface
    'Dim myForm as IBaseForm = CType(this.FindForm(), IBaseForm)

    If (this.BackColor = var_global.color_base) Then
        this.BackColor = var_global.color_base_dark
        myForm.cross_exit.BackColor = var_global.color_base_dark
    Else
        this.BackColor = var_global.color_base
        myForm.cross_exit.BackColor = var_global.color_base
    End If

End Sub
```

You'll need to implement an interface or a base class for all your forms so your properties can be accessed in drag_panel_switch.

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits BaseForm

End Class

Public Class Form2
    Inherits BaseForm

End Class


Public Class BaseForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Property cross_exit As PictureBox

End Class
```

or interface

```
Public Class Form1
    Implements IBaseForm

Public Property cross_exit As PictureBox

End Class

Public Class Form2
    Inherits IBaseForm

    Public Property cross_exit As PictureBox

End Class

Public Interface IBaseForm

    Property cross_exit As PictureBox

End Interface
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you give me some more information on this `public interface`. And cross_exit is a generated picturebox (also part of the standard layout), how would I make this via `interface`.